# parellel search with communications between threads

Tags: java, multithreading

Suppose I have an int array, an element `num` and 4 threads.
I'm giving each thread 1/4 of the array to search for `num`.
(The search method is given below)

```
public static boolean contains(int[] array, int minIdx, int maxIdx, int num) { ...}
```

At my "top level", I can schedule 4 threads to search 4 quarters of the array, but how do I ensure ALL the threads stop searching as soon as one of them finds the element (assuming there is NO duplicate in the array, hence the element can appear at most once).

P.S: You see, suppose my 4th thread found the element at the first iteration, I want the top-level method to return immediately as opposed to wait for other 3 guys to complete.

Comment: With a shared resource that all the threads observe.

Comment: *"as soon as one of them finds the element"* you may not want that because at a minimum that involves a volatile read for every single loop iteration which might prevent some loop optimizations. Checking every Nth iteration may be less costly unless the the equality check were really expensive. Caveat lector, checking the assembly output is more reliable than guesswork at what the optimizer might do.

Comment: @the8472 It isn't more reliable because it's highly implementation-specific. You are better off keeping to good programming idioms than trusting the assembly output of a single JVM run.

Comment: @the8472 I don't see why not? (Pls see my updated P.S)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need explicit signaling. You might consider the built-in interruption mechanism, or you may roll your own because it's very simple.

One idea: share an `AtomicBoolean` among all the threads and let each one periodically check it. When a thread finds the answer, it flips the boolean. The best option to achieve periodic checking is a nested loop:

```
for (int i = start; i < end && !done.get();) {
   for (int batchLimit = Math.min(i + BATCH_SIZE, end); i < batchLimit; i++) {
       // your logic
   }
}
```

This is the easiest for the JIT compiler to optimize.

The price of checking the value is very low whenever the value didn't change. It will be in the L3 cache. The case when the value did change is irrelevant because at that point you're done.

Comment: But by using the flag, would that cause blocking? (because all threads would have to block to ensure thread-safetiness)

Comment: Definitely no blocking. It's a plain `volatile` read operation, it's very efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Use a flag to signal when you found the answer and share it between threads. `AtomicBoolean` is a good option. 
Add the boolean to your loop end conditions for example

```
for (int i = minIdxs ; i < maxIdxs && found.get() == false; ++i){...}
```

Also share a [CountDownLatch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) of size 4 and countDown() when you are returning from each thread.

Have your main thread `await()` and it'll mean all threads gracefully finish before you move on in your main thread.

Comment: `Thread.join()` is enough to await thread completion. And I would _definitely_ recommend some batching instead of checking the boolean on each turn. Once every hundred would already drown out the cost of the read, but once in every 10,000 is all that's really needed to get good responsiveness.

Comment: Correct, `join()` might be used if you are creating the threads yourself but wont' work if say you're using an `ExecutorService` which isn't unlikely in this case. The latch works in both cases though. But I do like the idea of batching.

Comment: With an ExecutorService you'd have a `Future`.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a class who will act like a controller. this class will know each thread and every thread knows the controller. (its like an observer pattern)

If one thread finds the answer, the thread can tell it to the controller which can inform the other threads to stop.

```
class ControllerOfAllTheThreads{
ArrayList<TheClassesWhichDoTheSearch> list = new ArrayList<TheClassesWhichDoTheSearch>();

public void tellThemWeFoundHim(){
    for (TheClassesWhichDoTheSearch theThreads : list) {
        if(theThreads.isAlive() && !theThreads.isInterrupted())
            theThreads.interrupt();
    }
}
```

}